# Windows 7 Partition

Tags: partitioning

I have combined two partitions in my hp note book by using partition wizard. I restarted my laptop, It shows error no such partition. I inserted a windows installation disk. Opened cmd prompt and typed in it that "bootrec/fixmbr" and "bootrec/fixboot"
 and restarted again. But it does not show operating systems installed in my laptop. It started as windows 7.Please help me to choose my operating systems installed on my laptop. I have combined Local disk c which has Windows 7 software and local disk  e which has free of its capacity But some temporary files are in this local disk e. I do not know that where are operating systems installed. But before get these error, Isaw the operating systems list when start up. Please help me.

Comment: Which two partititions did you combine? What does your hard drive like? Were there more than one OS ?

Answer (score 0):

[Mark the partition as active](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779300(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_CMD) with [**diskpart**](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/300415) and then use [**bootsect**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749177(v=ws.10).aspx) to ensure it has at least a NT60 bootsector; tools like *bcdboot* and *bootrec* are then able to see the operating systems and correct the further BCD boot.

If not, then it sounds like combining the partitions may have formatted it; check if the OS data is still present.